# Check if a string contains only letters

Tags: kotlin

How I can make a function that take a string and return the result whether the string contain alphabet letter only or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

function `all` returns `true` if all characters match the given predicate.

```
fun String.onlyLetters() = all { it.isLetter() }

if (str.onlyLetters()) {
// only letters
}
else {

}
```

Comment: Minor suggestions: a name like `isOnlyLetters()` would be slightly more standard (and slightly more readable).  Also, it might be more logical (as well as shorter) to omit the empty-string check, and return `true` for an empty string.

Comment: @gidds yes, according to d-feverx's answer it should return true when string is empty. fixed

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `firstOrNull()` to search for the 1st non letter char and compare the result with `null`:

```
fun onlyLetters(s: String): Boolean = (s.firstOrNull { !it.isLetter() } == null)
```

or as an extension function:

```
fun String.onlyLetters(): Boolean = (firstOrNull { !it.isLetter() } == null)
```

Note that this way you will get `true` even if the string is empty.
If you don't want this then you should add another condition for the length like:

```
fun String.onlyLetters(): Boolean = length > 0 && (firstOrNull { !it.isLetter() } == null)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a simple regular expression to validate the input:

```
fun isOnlyLetters(word: String): Boolean {
val regex = "^[A-Za-z]*$".toRegex()
return regex.matches(word)}
```

Alternatively,

- making the regex `^[A-Za-z ]*$` (space after "z")would allow any amount of whitespace (such as in a phrase) at any point in the string (i.e. and still return true).
- making the regex `^[A-Za-z ]+$` (`*` -> `+`) would return false for an empty string(i.e. ensure that there is at least one character in the input, be it a letter or space).

Answer (score 0):

create an extension function isLettersOnly()

/*
* This fuction return true only if the string contain a-z or A-Z,
* Otherwise false*/

```
fun String.isLettersOnly(): Boolean {
    val len = this.length
    for (i in 0 until len) {
        if (!this[i].isLetter()) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

1.check a string value

```
fun main() {
    val text = "name"

    if (text.isLettersOnly()) {
        println("This is contain a-z,A-Z only")
    } else {
        println("This contain something else")

    }
}
```

output:
This is contain a-z,A-Z only

2.check a string value

```
fun main() {
    val text = "name 5"

    if (text.isLettersOnly()) {
        println("This is contain a-z,A-Z only")
    } else {
        println("This contain something else")

    }
}
```

output:
This contain something else

Comment: this is java style, not kotlin, and even in java it can be done like this `boolean containsOnlyLetters = text.chars().allMatch(Character::isLetter);`

Comment: can your please explain how to implement extension fun on java

Comment: extension function is just a wrapper, and I'm talking about content